# How can I install PyAudio in Mac M1

Tags: python, pyaudio, voice, assistant

I am trying to install PyAudio in my MacBook Air M1 for a while, tried all the possible ways to my knowledge and read the compleate official documentaion even i cant find the solution

```
xcode-select --install
brew remove portaudio
brew install portaudio
pip3 install pyaudio
```

Got an solution from an expert that find the portaudio location and include it while installing pyAudio, But searched my enterier hardisk and I cant find the brew/portaudio files.

Please help me!

Comment: did you restart your computer after doing `xcode-select --install`

Comment: yes tried restarting !

Comment: You should specify what exactly went wrong during your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the path of where portaudio is installing. Use that path to while installing pyaudio. For example, if it is in `/opt/homebrew`, you can use `pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/opt/homebrew/include' --global-option='-L/opt/homebrew/lib' pyaudio`.

Most likely the above command will solve your issue since it solved mine on an M1 Mac!

Comment: yep, but cant find the location of portaudio, searched my enteier hardisk

Comment: Try to run this `brew --prefix portaudio`